# How to reduce the number of Write Operations for a simple Entity?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, jpa-2.0

I have the following `Entity` :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DCOL", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("Alias")
public class Alias
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    @Basic
    private UUID from;
    @Basic
    private UUID to;
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
    private Date createdOn;

    public Alias() { /* intentionally blank */ }

    public Alias(@Nonnull final UUID from, @Nonnull final UUID to)
    {
        this.key = KeyFactory.createKey(Alias.class.getSimpleName(), from.toString());
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.createdOn = new Date();
    }
}
```

And here is the code that persists it :

```
final EntityManager em = EMF.TRANSACTIONS_OPTIONAL.createEntityManager();
try
{
    final Alias a = new Alias(from, to);
    em.persist(a);
}
finally
{
    em.close();
}
```

Currently it takes `6` Write Operations to the `Datastore` to persist this `Entity`.

*I reduced the number from `10` to `6` by marking `createdOn` with the `@Extension` to exclude it from the auto indexing. That is a `40%` decrease in write ops!*

Is there any way I can reduce the number of writes for something this simple?

Would using the low-level `Datastore` API directly make any improvement?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, your entity requires 6 write operations divided as follows:

- 1 write for the entity itself
- 1 write for the built-in `EntitiesByKind` index
- 2 writes for the `from` property (1 for the built-in index `EntitiesByProperty` and another for the built-in index `EntitiesByPropertyDesc`).
- 2 writes for the `to` property (1 for the built-in index `EntitiesByProperty` and another for the built-in index `EntitiesByPropertyDesc`).

The only opportunity you have at this point to reduce the number of writes is marking any of the `from` or `to` properties as unindexed as well (thus reducing the number of writes by 2 with each property).

You can see more information here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Understanding_write_costs